# Unable to put NA in the empty columns of dataset

Tags: r, kaggle

I am working on Titanic [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).The attribute `Cabin` is empty in most of the rows. So, I want to replace all those rows having empty values for `Cabin` column with `NA`.

To do this, I wrote:

`train[train$Cabin==" "] <- "NA"`

```
write.csv(train,file="editedtrain.csv")
```

But the file `editedtrain.csv` doesn't has `NA` in the rows having empty values for `Cabin` columns.

Following is the result of `head(train)` after running the above code.

```
          Ticket          Fare     Cabin   Embarked
1        A/5 21171          7.2500              S
2         PC 17599          71.2833   C85        C
3       STON/O2.3101282     7.9250              S
4           113803          53.1000  C123        S
5           373450          8.0500              S
6           330877           8.4583              Q
```

And the `dput`:

```
structure(
  list(
    PassengerId = 1:6,
    Survived = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,0L, 0L),
    Pclass = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L),
    Name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", "Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", "Allen, Mr. William Henry", "Moran, Mr. James"),
    Sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male"),
    Age = c(22, 38, 26, 35, 35, NA),
    SibSp = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
    Parch = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    Ticket = c("A/5 21171", "PC 17599", "STON/O2. 3101282", "113803", "373450", "330877"),
    Fare = c(7.25, 71.2833, 7.925, 53.1, 8.05, 8.4583),
    Cabin = c("", "C85", "", "C123", "", ""),
    Embarked = c("S", "C", "S", "S", "S", "Q")),
  .Names = c("PassengerId", "Survived", "Pclass", "Name", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Ticket", "Fare", "Cabin", "Embarked"),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: You need to have `train$Cabin[train$Cabin == ""] <- NA`

Comment: No,it's not working.Same changes take now also.

Comment: You need to show a small reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: The issue is best avoided altogether by adding `''` to the `na.strings` parameter of `read.csv`.

Comment: @akrun In my question now i have added the o/p of `head(train)`

Comment: In this case, `dput(head(train))` would be better than the table version.

Comment: Trying using `table(train$Cabin)` to see what those missing string values really are. E.g. they could be `" "` or `""` or something else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the `dput`, the `train$Cabin` missing values are `""`.

So in order to change this to `NA`, you can't put space inside the quotation mark.

You just need to do this `train$Cabin[train$Cabin==""] <- NA`

You need to specify you want the `Cabin` column to be changed, and r recognizes `NA` without the quotes.

---

As [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) commented, if you just read the `.csv` file with `na.strings = ""`, it will automatically do the job. It would be like this:

```
train <- read.csv("YOUR_PATH\\train.csv", stringAsFactors = F, na.strings = "")
```

---

Some tips:

- When you `read.csv()`, set `stringsAsFactors = F`, if you want your characters columns to continue as characters, and not factors
- When you `write.csv()`, set `row.names = F` if you don't want it to create a column with lines id's.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I updated the answer. But my point with the tips was just for giving some extra info that I thought would be usefull.